# What is /usr/bin/parity?

Tags: software-uninstall, cleanup

While trying to free some disk-space, I found the following file in my /usr/bin:

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 29082328 May 17  2017 /usr/bin/parity
```

What is this application? Is it safe to remove it? And how do I remove it? (I tried `sudo apt remove parity` but it said "After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.")

Comment: What does `dpkg -S /usr/bin/parity` print?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you've been experimenting with Ethereum clients on your system it might be a part of [Parity Wallet](https://parity.io/). If you can verify that Parity Wallet is what you have installed, it's safe to uninstall as it's not a part of your system. Depending on how it was installed, Parity might be running as a snap.

---

You can try the following to uninstall it if it's running as a snap:

`sudo snap remove parity` or `sudo snap remove parity --edge`

If it's a deb then try this:

`sudo apt purge parity`

Edit: Removed note because now we know that's what was installed